# How to avoid 429 error when using grequests?

Tags: python, html-parsing, http-status-code-429, grequests

I want to make a parser using "grequests", but as expected, due to many requests, i get an error 429.

```py
import grequests


sites = [f"https://fantlab.ru/work{i}" for i in range(1, 10)]

response = (grequests.get(url, timeout=5)  for url in sites)
resp = grequests.map(response)

print(resp)
```

```
[<Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [200]>, <Response [404]>, <Response [429]>...]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A 429 (Too many requests) status code is returned when you are sending too many requests. You could try showing down the requests (using `time.sleep(n)` from the `time` module, or see if the owner of the server can increase your quota.

Comment: Okay, I understand your logic, but how should I use time.sleep and grequests at the same time, it's not requests. I tried doing it like this [code](http://pastie.org/p/6cpxiXQejSmcM74sW1m5aW) it works slower, but it doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: Sorry, I can't think of any other solutions other than asking the website owner